# fading out a div in relation to yOffset Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fade out a Div in relation to The scroll When I Scroll Down the opacity fades out and when when I scroll up it fades back in

**CSS:**

```css
.HeroImg{
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: 414px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;}

#hero{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="HeroImg" id="Hero">
    <h1>Exemple</h1>
    <h2>Exemple</h2>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
<script>
        var hero, yPos;
        function yScroll() {
            pagetop = document.getElementById('hero');
            yPos = window.pageYOffset;
            if (yPos > 150) {
                hero.style.opacity = "0";
            } else {
                hero.style.opacity = "1";
            }

        };
</script>
```

and nothing happened 
Can anyone here tell me Where's the problem ?

Comment: Check out **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828349/fading-out-a-div-in-relation-to-yoffset-position/26828428#26828428)**..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems i fixed here http://jsfiddle.net/8c2dg7nj/1/

1- you were using an uninitialized variable hero, you were using the wrong name

```js
hero = document.getElementById('hero');
```

instead of

```js
pagetop = document.getElementById('hero');
```

2- Id is case sensetive so id="hero" not "Hero"

3-you were never calling your javascript function. I added a call on scroll

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
    yScroll();
})
```

Comment: Also note that on scroll doesn't mean just moving the mouse wheel or arrow keys, it means actually having the page scroll. If you want it on mouse wheel or arrow click without scrolling you will have to capture these events and call ur function there

Comment: Can you possibly link your website or insert the code in a JsFiddle?

Comment: This is The Whole project
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0XSf5aaT1jWQS14Q0g3SjFkeWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I dont quite understand what you want to do, can you explain to me what is the functionality you are aiming for?

Comment: What I want to do is just like in this site : 
http://peekaboodesign.co.uk/
fade in and out in The hero section